# make second span wrap below itself and not the first one

Tags: html, css

Hello I have this code

```
<div class="test">
    <span class="first-span">first span</span>
    <span class="second-span">some long long long long text</span>
</div>
```

with css

```
.test{
    width:150px;
    margin:10px
}
.first-span{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.second-span{
    border:1px solid blue
}​
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/66AUy/)

Now as you all can see in the fiddle the "long" word from second span is wrapping and coming under word "first". But what I need is that "long" should come under word "some"

Is this possible some how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using display as table?

```css
.test {
  display: table;
}

.test span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.test .first-span {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span class="first-span">first span</span>
  <span class="second-span">some long long long long text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way spans work, or all "inline" elements. To combat this we can `display: block; float: left;` the float: left makes the span only take up as much room as it needs.

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/66AUy/1/)

Comment: but in your demo "long text" is coming under "first span"

Comment: @Ankur Not for me it isn't? :o What browser are you using

Comment: Google chrome 23.0.1271.97 and this is a snap of what i am getting https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/span-snap.PNG

Comment: @Ankur add `margin-bottom:50px;` to `.first-span`

Comment: that works, but then I will need to hard code it into css and i don't think that is the right way to go about it, as the content of second span might be longer

Comment: Do you know how wide the blue span will be? I don't think this is possible without some sort of hard coded value